# How to exctract a string from the following HTML page using PHP

Tags: preg-match

Got stuck at some stuff. In short, I need to extract some certain data from a webpage.
Basically, I need to extract **/title/tt0118615/** from

`<a href="/title/tt0118615/" onclick="(new Image()).src='/rg/find-media-title/media_strip/images/b.gif?link=/title/tt0118615/';">Anaconda</a>"`

by using **preg_match()** or whatever other ways. That's a piece of the code from the page which is extracted by the php code below:

```
 <?php
$url = "http://www.imdb.com/find?s=tt&q=Anaconda";
$raw = file_get_contents($url);
echo preg_match ("/^(href=\"\/title\/tt)\"$/", $raw, $data);
echo "data: $data[1]";
?>
```

I know I'm wrong at the pattern, so that's why I'm posting my question here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this pattern will work in your case:

```
preg_match("/a href=\"([^\"]*)\"/", $raw, $data);
```

$data will be an array containing your results, $data[1] is the one you're looking for

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That works! I had to slightly change it but you brought me the clue! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://www.imdb.com/find?s=tt&q=Anaconda";
$raw = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match_all('%b\.gif\?link=(/title/.*?)\'%i', $raw, $imdbcode, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$imdbcode = $imdbcode[1][0];
echo $imdbcode; #echo's  /title/tt0118615/
```